# Show that $\int \left(1+\left|\xi\right|^2\right)^s\left|\hat{f}(\xi)\right|^2\,d\xi = \sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} \int \left|D^k f(x)\right|^2\,dx$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

From what I understand,
\begin{align}
\int \left(1+\left|\xi\right|^2\right)^s\left|\hat{f}(\xi)\right|^2\,d\xi
&=
\sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} \int \left|\xi\right|^{2k}\left|\hat{f}(\xi)\right|^2\,d\xi\\
&\overset{\color{red}{(?)}}{=}
\sum_{k=0}^s {s\choose k} \int \left|D^k f(x)\right|^2\,dx
\end{align}
where $\hat{f}(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(x)$.

I understand that Plancherel theorem was applied in $\overset{\color{red}{(?)}}{=}$ and that
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{D^\alpha f(x)\right\} = \xi^\alpha \hat{f}(\xi) \tag{1}
$$

But my confusion lies primarily in the fact that $\alpha$ is a multi-index notation but $k$ is an integer, so I am not sure how/why $(1)$ can be applied in $\overset{\color{red}{(?)}}{=}$.

Any guidance regarding this is much appreciated; thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just some integration by parts. For example, with $2$ derivatives:
$$
\int |\partial_{i} \partial_{j} f|^2 = \int (\partial_{i} \partial_{j} f) (\partial_{i} \partial_{j} f)
\\= \int (\partial_{i}^2 f) (\partial_{j}^2 f)$$
and the result follows by summing on $i$ and $j$ and taking the Fourier transform of the right-hand side. I let you generalize to $k$ derivatives ;)